# I am trying to run a large .csv file through aspect code but it keeps returning this: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'csv'

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
for csv_file in os.listdir(folder_path):
    if csv_file.endswith(".csv"):
        paraview_time_step = int(csv_file.split(".")[1])
```

But I get an error message that says `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'csv'`. What is wrong, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Yes; that is because you did not ask it to split a line of text from the file, you asked it to split **the name** of the file. But *you should not try to write your own code to process CSV files*; there is support provided in the standard library (as well as by third-party libraries like Pandas). Please see the linked duplicate.

Comment: `csv_file` is the name of a file like **"foo.csv"** not the contents of that file. Alternatively, if you feel the filename is something like **"1.csv"** then perhaps you wanted `int(csv_file.split(".")[0])` to get `1` the 0-th item in the list.

Comment: As a side note for future questions, please re-read the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). If you use indentation to mark a block of code, you must put an *extra* four spaces in front of *each line of code*. You may find it easier and clearer to use code fences instead. Please also do not write try to write a question using comments inside a single code block; instead, write prose normally, and use several code blocks as necessary to show how to cause the problem and what goes wrong.